# How to update database backup schedule settings with ml-gradle?

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle

I am trying to change scheduled MarkLogic database backup settings with ml-gradle. I am able to deploy a database with *gradle mlDeploy*. But when changing it's scheduled backup properties I get a "database configurations differ" error while running mlDeploy again.

The current json file for the database looks like this:

```
  "database-name" : "caspar-test",
  "range-element-index" : [ {
    "scalar-type" : "string",
    "namespace-uri" : "CHANGEME",
    "localname" : "CHANGEME",
    "collation" : "http://marklogic.com/collation/",
    "range-value-positions" : false,
    "invalid-values" : "reject"
  } ],
  "database-backup": [ {
    "backup-id": "1373474833703299773",
    "backup-enabled": true,
    "backup-directory": "/backup/caspar-test",
    "backup-type": "daily",
    "backup-period": 1,
    "backup-start-time": "13:01:00Z",
    "backup-timestamp": "2019-09-06T13:55:25.243878Z",
    "max-backups": 2,
    "backup-security-database": true,
    "backup-schemas-database": true,
    "backup-triggers-database": true,
    "include-replicas": true,
    "incremental-backup": false,
    "journal-archiving": false,
    "journal-archive-path": "",
    "journal-archive-lag-limit": 15
  } ]
}
```

For the test I set "backup-enabled" to false. Running ml-gradle shows

```
Logging HTTP response body to assist with debugging: {"errorResponse":{"statusCode":"500", "status":"Internal Server Error", "messageCode":"CMA-ERRORCONFIG", "message":"CMA-ERRORCONFIG (err:FOER0000): MANAGE-CONFLICTINGCONFIGerr:FOER00001.0-mlA conflict has been detected: MANAGE-CONFLICTINGCONFIG: (err:FOER0000) A conflict has been detected:  database configurations differ: database-backupsfalse database configurations differ: database-backups/MarkLogic/manage/models/database-idempotent.xqy7186xdmp:function(fn:QName(\"http://marklogic.com/manage/database/idempotent\",\"check-database-property-idempotent-database-backups\"))(<configuration/>, xs:unsignedLong(\"11315473330229343670\"), <database-backups xmlns=\"http://marklogic.com/manage/database/properties\">...</database-backups>)config<configuration/>dbidxs:unsignedLong(\"11315473330229343670\")prop<database-backups xmlns=\"http://marklogic.com/manage/database/properties\">...</database-backups>alist<database-backup xmlns=\"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">...</database-backup>plist<database-backup xmlns=\"http://marklogic.com/manage/database/properties\">...</database-backup>compare<database-backup xmlns=\"http://marklogic.com/xdmp/database\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">...</database-backup>1.0-ml/MarkLogic/manage/models/database-idempotent.xqy9011dmodi:check-database-property-update-idempotent(<configuration/>, xs:unsignedLong(\"11315473330229343670\"), <database-backups…
```

In my understanding scheduled database backup settings can be changed via API as they are being updated via PUT. Therefore I expected ml-gradle to handle this task without issues. Am I missing something here?

### update

If you need to dig further with similar issues: Call "ml-gradle" with "-i" as it will dump the json it tried to apply. You can save this json to a file and apply it yourself by using a command like

```
curl -X POST --anyauth --user user:password -H 'Content-type: application/json' --header "Accept: application/json" -d@file.json http://host.name:8002/manage/v3
```

Be aware that MarkLogic offers a v2 API that has PUT and POST and v3 that only accepts POST for changes. The current issues result from using /manage/v3

Comment: Try making the same request via curl or a similar HTTP client - you will likely get the same error. That's all ml-gradle is doing - reading the contents of your database file and then sending them to the Manage API. If you run "gradle -i mlDeployDatabases", you'll see the exact endpoint that ml-gradle is hitting (and mlDeployDatabases only deploys databases instead of everything, so it's faster to test with).

Comment: Thanks, @rjrudin, for the hint. I tested the code now with curl and see that it's a result coming from MarkLogic directly. Still I do not know if it's correct, that changes aren't being applied with PUT requests against the v2 API but this seems to be another topic then. I'll continue to dig further.